# Cycle through Materials with Animation Nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials, animation-nodes

I have a project where I have an object (wristband) that has six different color options. I created one Cycles material for each option having six different materials.

In order to save setup time of creating a wristband for each material, I would like to use Animation Nodes to have one wristband but be able to cycle through the six materials based on the frame number I am on. Is this possible? I am very new to Animation Nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add your materials to a list, get a list element based on the frame, and set that material to the object using the *Object Material Output* node.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: So I just found out that even though this solution works, this combination of nodes causes Blender to crash when I hit render. I tried hitting render with the same scene without these nodes and it works but as soon as I add them in, the program will crash. Do you know of an alternate way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: @Mswan This is a known bug in Blender that haven't been solved yet. So I am not sure.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so close! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Mswan Please accept the answer if it answers your question.